# c# program involve Web Service work in VS2010 debug but not work when built into release

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, debugging, release

I use VS2010 to write a c# project, which involves web service calling. I set all dlls' properties as "copy to local". When I debug the program in VS2010, it works. Then I build the program as release, e.g., test.exe. I double click test.exe, but it seems that it does not work. Any suggestions are appreciated.
Or could you suggest when I run test.exe, what files should I copy into the same directory with the exe file?

Answer (score 0):

You need all of the files included in the bin\release directory (you can't just take the .exe file by itself).  If you are attempting to run the executable from the bin\release directory you could always validate that it has all of the same files as the bin\debug directory (besides the .pdb files).